# Partial orders and equivalence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $S = \{ u,v,w \} $  List all equivalence relations on S. How many of these are also partial
orders?

Well I found five total equivalences classes but right now I'm confused as to which are partial orders. The confusion is because I'm thinking in transitive terms. For example, one equivalence relation I found is:

$$\{ (u,u),(v,v),(w,w),(u,v),(v,u) \}$$

Anti symmetric means that $(u,v) \land (v,u) \rightarrow u=v$ but $u$ and $v$ are two different variables and so they're not the same. So this means that they're antisymmetric? I don't know why I'm stuck here.

Comment: +1 for showing work/good question, but I concur with @BrianM.Scott that this is a duplicate (and am voting as such)

Comment: Yup! Once again someone asked it before I did. Thanks!